# Selenium - No Such Element Found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to set up autologin for snow dev instance using selenium+python and below is code snippet I tried but for some strange reason every time it gives me an error "no such element found" or timeout exception as per different setup I tried , though the element is quite available on html page.

Me new to selenium/python so any help/suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks,

**Explicit wait**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
uName = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_name")))
# un = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'user_name')))
uName.send_keys("admin")
```

**throws timeout exception**

```
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/Users/Desktop/PySelenium/snow.py", line 21, in <module>
    uName = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_name")))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Users\Desktop\PySelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

**with sleep time**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://dev91011.service-now.com/")
time.sleep(120)
uName = driver.find_element_by_id("user_name")
uName.send_keys("admin")
```

**throws Unable to locate element error**

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Users\Desktop\PySelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="user_name"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
```

**locators as from snow page**

`<div><label class="control-label" for="user_name">User name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="" autocomplete="off"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items you are trying to find are inside of an iframe. You need to switch the context of the driver to the frame first.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://dev91011.service-now.com/")
time.sleep(120)
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#gsft_main')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
uName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="user_name"]')
uName.send_keys("admin")
```

Comment: tried above too but still same.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[id="user_name"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)